# oracle 10g convert date column with timestamp to dd-mon-yyyy format

Tags: datetime, oracle10g, typeconverter

Hi am trying to convert column defined as date to date with format DD-MON-YYYY but can't get it working

```
 select 
   to_date(to_char
   (DESIGN_COMPLETION_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY') as Assessment_Completion_Date
    from nbi_dates
```

Also Tried

```
 Select to_date(DESIGN_COMPLETION_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') as Assessment_Completion_Date
    from nbi_dates
```

What works is, but I can't do any calculations on it as it is char

```
 Select to_char(DESIGN_COMPLETION_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') as Assessment_Completion_Date
    from nbi_dates
```

Thanks

Comment: `DATE` values do not have any format. The client decides how to represent the data as a string, the database does not. Does the 'can't do any calculations' part mean you have a date with a time component and want to only use the date part, discarding the time? (I can't tell if that's what the title implies).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `DATE` that includes a time portion but are only interested in the actual date part, you can use the [`trunc`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions220.htm) function:

```
select trunc(design_completion_date) as assessment_completion_date from nbi_dates
```

An example of the difference using `sysdate`; notice the time on the `trunc`'d version has been set to midnight:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate, trunc(sysdate) from dual;

SYSDATE             TRUNC(SYSDATE)
------------------- -------------------
11/04/2013 15:14:31 11/04/2013 00:00:00
```

A `DATE` has no inherent format. `DD-MON-YYYY` is a format mask applied to display the date, or to convert it to a string representation, which is usually only necessary for display anyway. What you have as your third option is right for that purpose, but not if you want to  do any further date calculations with the result.

Comment: I agree with you Alex a date is a date but some users who are pulling the data do not understand this. They want date in 'dd-mon-yyyy' format and to be able to do stuff like if assessment_completion_date > q1  blah blah blah. I do wish in certain circumstances killing was legal but its not and I am  stuck

Comment: @Varun - if the users want to be able to do that with a string value for `q1` of say `'11-Apr-2013'` then their value has to be converted to a date. If they won't do that as `... > to_date('11-Apr-2013', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')` then you're a bit stuck. Even if you can get their client settings have `NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-Mon-YYYY'` they have to at least do `to_date('11-Apr-2013')`, and as we know implicit masks are still evil. Is a function that takes the string date a possibility?

Comment: I am passing the values as a View, please do not mind but I am a BA doing dev work due to budget constraints, So I am not sure if we can have functions in a View.

Comment: @Varun - not sure what you mean about passing the values as a view. I think it would be helpful if you update the question with what you're doing with the data and how you want to call/display/compare it. WHat you want to achieve basically as it isn't clear and I'm guessing (wrongly, apparently!).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select to_date(to_char(DESIGN_COMPLETION_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY') as Assessment_Completion_Date
from nbi_dates
```

or simply (in case you want date object for calculations but not for rendereing)

```
    Select DESIGN_COMPLETION_DATE as Assessment_Completion_Date
from nbi_dates
```

Comment: That's what the OP showed first, and has no effect - you're converting to a string and back to a date, so what's the point?

Comment: TO_DATE() is the right one in this scenario but it accepts String parameters.